# MSGraph FindmeetingTimes Meeting Duration?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, iso8601

With Microsoft Graph Findmeetingtimes API how could I change meeting duration to 2.5 Hour (2Hour 30minute)

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_findmeetingtimes

in variable `"meetingDuration": "PT2H"` I try `PT2.5H` or `PT2H30M` and it's not work

Answer (score 0):

I gave it a try on my end, PT2H30M works to indicate a duration of 2 hours and 30 minutes. Just created a [pull request to improve documentation](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/pull/1583).